# QGIS - Resolution issue

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution

I have 2 images. One of them was using a custom CRS that had pixel of 463m. I used warp(reprojection) on this and used the epsg4326 CRS. This then converted the image from 463m pixel to 0.00205 pixels. My question is, is that 0.00205 pixel resolution equivalent to 463m in the image. The reason I ask is because I want to use that pixel resolution in another raster file to make it the same as 463m pixel but in terms of degrees (e.g. 0.00205).
[image]
I basically want to resample the raster file which has pixel resolution of 0.0025 pixel resolution to a resolution of 463m but I cant do it in meters so I tried to do it the way I explained.

[image]

Comment: One degree at the equator measures about 110 km from East to West, while at the polar circle one degree from East to West is only about 36 km. So no, you can't make that assumption.

Comment: @Erik Thank you for the response. So I assume I cannot just convert the coordinate system and hope that the resolutions essentially make a conversion. How do I fix this now? How do I make resolutions the same when one uses a custom CRS that I cannot use on another raster file. I want to resample a raster file which has 0.0025 pixel resolution(this raster was created using 100m spatial resolution satellite) to be 500m instead. Of course I need to use same CRS to do this, but not sure how to make it the same in meters or convert it in degrees or something so that I can match the resolutions

Comment: There is some quite important information missing - e.g. the extent of your layer and the area of interest as well as your intention/workflow: what do you need this for (to see if there is a better way to achieve that).